# Dynamically replace inserted template value in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I create one tinymce with some templates, but in this templates I have some keys to change just like this:

```
tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea', plugins: "template",
        language_url: '/langs/pt_BR.js',
        template_replace_values: {
            username: "Jack Black"
          } ,
         templates: [{title: 'Modelo 11', description: 'Descrição Modelo 1', content: '<strong> Titulo</strong><br> aqui tem alguma coisa {$username}'}]
    });
```

But I wanna my username be dynamic then I will put one text field in my page and change the `${username}` for what my user types in the text field

Comment: When are you wanting to replace that value?  When the content is inserted into TinyMCE via the template?